# PHP: Getting a Proper escaped String from json_encode

Tags: php, regex, json, string

I am reading a json file in php which and storing it in a variable whose value is:

```
$json = {"inp" : "0"}
```

However, I need to pass this as an input to an application which requires it strictly to be of the format:

```
"{\"inp\" : \"0\"}"
```

I have tried `str_replace('"', '\"')`, but this replaces `"` by `\\"` , giving:

```
"{\\"inp\\" : \\"0\\"}"
```

which is not accepted as input by the application.

ANy directions on how to achieve the desired string `"{\"inp\" : \"0\"}"` will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the `str_replace` should work. How did you get that output with the double slashes? How are you "passing this to an application"?

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting double quotes. Any ideas?
There is an api to which the parameter needs to be passed

Comment: I suspect that there are single backslashes in the string, only the output method does echo them escaped (so that you can use the output as a string literal). Please show us the code that you use for outputting them!

Comment: @bergi - Here it is:

$inp = "'".$inp."'";
$inp = json_encode($inp);
error_log($inp);

Comment: https://eval.in/161695

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = json_encode('{"inp" : "0"}');
```

Comment: I need to set the value of $json to "{\"inp\" : \"0\"}"

Comment: Notice that this does not only escape quotes, but many more things.

Comment: This gives "{\\"inp\\" : \\"0\\"}". Double slashes again

Comment: @Bergi yes, and i am guessing his api will expect those to be escaped as well. I have encountered this weird double json_encodeing before

Comment: @user1628340 no it doesnt.

Comment: @user1628340 you mean your api does not accept double escaped quotes , right ?

Comment: @user1628340 This outputs exactly what you asked for `"{\"inp\" : \"0\"}"`

Comment: Yes, but my system seems to be giving double quotes :( Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @aelor: yes, the api does not accept double escaped quotes

Comment: @user1628340 please show some more code, there must be an exrtra step causing the double slashes

Comment: @user574632-  Here it is: 
$inp = "'".$inp."'"; 
$inp = json_encode($inp); 
error_log($inp);

Comment: @user1628340 Well that doesnt look at all like the code in my answer does it?? Why are you using completely different code and then saying its not working???

Comment: @user574632- its the same. I am putting single quotes outside the json braces and then doing the same as you did

Comment: OK well this is extremely weird. maybe you error_log function is screwing it up? Im afraid i cant help beyond that. As aelor showed, this should work as expected

Comment: @user574632: Do you have magic quotes enabled? What does `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc());` output?